# What kinds of functions can be expanded into a form of an infinite continued fraction?

Tags: functions, continued-fractions

In [this](http://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.63.46) 1943 paper by Hudson on the theory of elastic waves in beams the author offers an interesting way to calculate a function defined as

$$
\theta_n (z)=\frac{z J'_n (z)}{J_n (z)}
$$

with $z$ either real or imaginary, $J_n(z)$ - Bessel function, and $'$ denoting $z$ derivative.

To simplify the computation of this function he offers a continued fraction expansion for it based on the recurrence relation for Bessel functions.

$$
\theta_n (z)=n-\frac{z^2}{2(n+1)-\frac{z^2}{2(n+2)-...}}
$$

So my question - is there a theory about expansion of functions into continued fractions and what kinds of functions can be expressed this way? And what about the interval (ring) of convergence for such fractions?

---

Edit:
[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/415552/269624) answer offers a lot of information.

Comment: See [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_continued_fraction_formula)

Comment: You're welcome. There are a lot of examples and methods.

Comment: There may be a lot of different examples, but I was asking more about the general theory. The wiki page you provided contains only one method and two simple examples.

Comment: In general, if $f(z)$ is a solution of a second-order ODE with polynomial coefficients, $\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}$ can be written as a continued fraction (whose domain of convergence, sometimes, is not easy to understand).

Comment: @Yuri It is a bit difficult to apply a general formula. As you might find inexpansable functions in terms of continued fractions

Comment: There are two particularly general continued fractions,i.e Euler's continued fraction as mentioned by Oussama Boussif and [Gauss's continued fraction](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssContinuedFraction.html)

Comment: Thank you all for your answers!